# Finding similar properties within a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `Employee`:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string SSN;
    public string empNumber;
    public int someValue;
}
```

I want to check if the employees share a similar SSN AND a similar empNumber. I have a `List<Employee>` available to search through. Employees cannot have the same SSN and empNumber. Ultimately, I want to populate a list that contains the employees that share only SSN and empNumber. If this list is not a size 0, then I know to send an error message.

I know I can use LINQ or a foreach, but I am not sure which would be best for this situation.

Comment: "share a similar SSN AND a similar empNumber" similar or equal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a pretty simple `GroupBy` - assuming your `List<Employee>` is in a variable `employees`:

```
var dupes = employees.GroupBy(e => new {e.SSN, e.empNumber})
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

The variable `dupes` will now contain an enumerable list of anonymous objects with the properties

- `SSN`
- `empNumber`

which will represent your duplicates. Each item is also itself an `IEnumerable<Customer>` containing the duplicates themselves (from the original list).

Comment: This will give me the list of employees that share both the SSN and empNumber? If so, wow that was easy.

Comment: @rocat: to get a `List<Employee>` you need `dupes.SelectMany(g => g).ToList()`

Comment: @rocat - see update (and also comment above). Hopefully clarifies a little.